# sales_order_creditmemo_save_after event in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I just check the event list of magento 2

There is no `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after` event so which event is call after creditmemo save from admin?

Answer (score 5):

There is a `sales_order_creditmemo_save_after`

Every model gets it's own event fired made up from the $_eventPrefix variable on the class (default is 'core_abstract') followed by _save_after. Specifically $this->_eventPrefix . '_save_after'.

In the \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Creditmemo class, the $_eventPrefix var is overwritten with `sales_order_creditmemo`

It is a bit magic.

Anyway, in your observer you can get it by calling $observer->getDataObject();