# Relevant event for admin side in Magento 1 to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I need relevant event for Magento 1 to magento 2? I have given Magento 1 event below?

```
sales_order_creditmemo_save_after
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the same for Magento 2.

Found this in \vendor\magento\module-catalog-inventory\etc\events.xml:

```
<event name="sales_order_creditmemo_save_after">
    <observer name="inventory" instance="Magento\CatalogInventory\Observer\RefundOrderInventoryObserver"/>
</event>
```

**Edit:**

I've found a similar answer to this question [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/103022/50771).